# OnCreate and onActivityResult called when I finish the activity for result

Tags: java, android, appcompatactivity

I have Activity A. it displays some data retrieved from the server by calling void loadData() in onCreate.

User click a button which open a new Activity B for result. Once it finishes it back to Activty A. **onActivtyresult** should **call loadData()** to reload the data.

When Activty B finishes both onCreate and onActivityResult  called as A was destroyed. Which is not Ok for me.

The question is:

- Dose activity A always will be destroyed and onCreate will be called? Is this documented as I could not find any thing about this. If this is the case then I will call loadData only in onCreate.

  If not I have to call loadData from onActivityResult also, which again leaded to call loadData 2 time in some cases, which I dont want.

  Class A:

  ```
      public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            .... creation code
            loadData(); // will be called first time activity created as well when back from the activity B
      }

      public void createNew() {
           Intent createService =  new Intent(this,CreateService.class);
          startActivityForResult(createService, 1001);
          overridePendingTransition(R.anim.out_top,R.anim.fp);
      } 

      public void onActivityResult(int i, int i2, Intent intent) {
          super.onActivityResult(i, i2, intent);
          if (i2 != -1) {
              loadData(); ///will be called when back from Activty B
            }
      }
  ```

  Class B:

  ```
      public void on taskFinish() {
          setResult(1);
          finish();
          overridePendingTransition(R.anim.s_right, R.anim.s_in_right);
      }
  ```

Comment: show me the code of A and B

Comment: Please post your code so that we can understand your problem properly.

Comment: I Added a my code

Answer (score 1):

I have come with a work around like this

```
     boolean loaded = false;
     void onCreate() {
        loadData();
        loaded=true;
     }

    public void createNew() {
        loaded = false;  /// Set before start the new Activity
        Intent createService =  new Intent(this,CreateService.class);
        startActivityForResult(createService, 1001);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.out_top,R.anim.fp);
     } 

     public void onActivityResult(int i, int i2, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(i, i2, intent);
        if (i2 != -1) {
           if (!loaded) {
             loadData();
             loaded = true;
          }
       }
     }
```

I have 2 scansion

1- Activity created form scrach- loadData will be called once in OnCrate()

2- Start new Activity for result - set loaded = false

a- after back for result if activity destroyed then loaded == true in onCreate and loadData will be called once. then onActivityResult will be called but loadData will not be called.

b- after back for result if Activity not destroyed then loaded = false and 
               loadData will be called

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no guarantee that Activity A will be destroyed.  You'd need to find some way of tracking whether the data needs to be reloaded - perhaps you could pass back a timestamp or something similar in the result from Activity B that you could use to check if the data you have in Activity A is up-to-date.